# Git private repos without password

Tags: git, github

I work on private git repos from github and everytime I pull or push I need to type my github username and password. Is there a way to make it not to ask for password every time?

I using Xubuntu GNU/Linux with command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use SSH connection rather than HTTPS.

Just create a key, give it to Github you should be good to go: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

## Update:

If you are already using HTTPS, you can easily change the remote's url to SSH:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user/repo.git`

Now you will be able to `push/pull` over SSH. More information can be found on [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url)

If you are cloning a new repo, make sure to use SSH clone url provided by Github on the repo's page.

Comment: I have ssh key and it's on github, without it you can't work with github at all. I've cloned the repo using https link on github repo page.

Comment: @jcubic, this is the correct answer. But when you use an `https://` URL your SSH keys will be ignored because you're *not connecting over SSH*, you're connecting over HTTPS. Switch your remote from `https://...` to `git@github.com...` and your SSH keys will become relevant. (Also, it's incorrect that you can't work with GitHub without SSH keys. If you're happy with the HTTPS workflow, SSH keys are not required at all.)

Comment: @Chris yes, but he didn't explain that ssh don't use user/password but the key and for https don't use ssh key. He tell me to generate the key and I already have one. I simple didn't notice that I don't use ssh. So generating a key will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the github website: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-linux

Password caching

The last option you set will tell Git that you don't want to type your username and password every time your computer talks to GitHub.

Tips:

You need Git 1.7.10 or newer to use the credential helper.
The credential helper only works when you clone a GitHub repository using an HTTPS URL. If you clone GitHub repositories using SSH, then you authenticate using SSH keys instead of a username and password. For help setting up an SSH connection, see Generating SSH Keys.
To use this option, you need to turn on the credential helper so that Git will save your password in memory for some time:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
# Set git to use the credential memory cache
```

By default Git will cache your password for 15 minutes. You can change this if you like.

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
# Set the cache to timeout after 1 hour (setting is in seconds)
```